# I want to use altered "terraformed" images of Mars with the Google Maps API. Am I violating Google's Terms of Service?

Tags: google-maps

So, I am working on a web application that uses a "terraformed" version of Mars using Google Maps.
[Here is an example.](http://www.hoofman.org/mars/mars.html)

To do this, I used the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image), that displays tiles from the Moon. To get the proper tiles of Mars, I previously downloaded the tiles from Google Mars, used a program to change their color, and renamed them so the code could read them easily.

I'm concerned that in downloading and altering the tile images, I have violated Google's Terms of Service, particularly 10.1.1(a) ( No Access to Maps API(s) Except Through the Service). Since I have used code other than the API to download and modify the tiles, am I violating the TOS?

However, I was able to find OTHER images from another website. If I downloaded the tiles from that website, modified them, and used them in my code, would that still be in violation of TOS (since the images didn't originate from Google)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use) not coding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the particular article bears on that.

However, there's 10.1.3 [...] (a) No Unauthorized Copying, Modification, Creation of Derivative Works, or Display of the Content. You must not copy, translate, modify, or create a derivative work (including creating or contributing to a database) of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof except as explicitly permitted under these Terms. For example, **the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles;**